# matlab bar graph: grey color

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, matlab-figure

I have the following code in Matlab, It works properly, but I couldn't change the color of graphs to **grey**.

```
y=[0.3435 0.35 0.3798 0.58 0.6491 0.6612];
bar(y);
Labels={'A','   B', '      C','   D', '    E','  F'};
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:4, 'XTickLabel', []); 
set(gca,'fontsize',10);
ylabel('F-measure','FontSize',10)
axis([0 7 0 1])
text(0.6:numel(y), -.04*ones(1,numel(y)), Labels, 'interpreter', 'TeX', 'Fontsize', 9)
```

I tried FaceColor function, but it didn't worked!
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please expand a little on how you tried the `FaceColor` property, and what do you mean by "it didn't worked", as in it gave you an error, or change to a wrong color, or did nothing but no error displayed and so on.

Comment: bar(y,'FaceColor', 'grey');

Comment: 'grey' is not a valid color definition in matlab. You should use a RGB triplet like `[0.75 0.75 0.75]`. For more information on colors check https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html

Comment: The only colors with long names are _yellow_, _magenta_, _cyan_, _red_, _green_, _blue_, _white_ and _black_. These have short names `y`, `m`, `c`, `r`, `g`, `b`, `w` and `k` respectively.

Comment: @NoelSeguraMeraz Please transform your comment into an answer, so it could be accepted.

Comment: Sure, I can do that

Answer (score 1):

From the comments I see that you are using incorrectly the `FaceColor` property.

You said you tried

```
bar(y,'FaceColor', 'grey');
```

The problem with this is that `'grey'` is not a valid color definition in Matlab.

There are 3 ways of defining colors, RGB triplets, short names and long names. Short and long names are very limited, there are only 8 colors predefined. White, black, red, green, blue, cyan, magenta and yellow. For any other color you need to define it as a RGB triplet, which is a vector of three elements from 0 to 1 representing the intensity of each channel.

In your case grey is most colors that have same intensity on the three channels, and as such this should work for you:

```
bar(y,'FaceColor', [0.75 0.75 0.75]);
```

If you have further doubts, please check matlab documentation on colors https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html